# How to populate FullCalendar with events using AJAX?

Tags: c#, ajax, fullcalendar

I try to put events on the FullCalendar plugin. 
With an AJAX call, I go in my C# WebMethod where I take some records in the database, then I return from the WebMethod an Array with the differents events.

Here is my Ajax with the display of the calendar :

```
var source = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "Default.aspx/GetEvents",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{ userId: 1}',
    success: function (doc) {
        source = [doc.d[0], doc.d[1], doc.d[2]];

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: '',
                right: 'month,basicWeek, agendaFourDay',
            },
            views: {
                agendaFourDay: {
                    type: 'agenda',
                    duration: { week: 1 },
                    buttonText: '7 day'
                }
            },
            height: 650,
            dayClick: function (date, view) {
                alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
                alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
                // change the day's background color just for fun
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                $("#AddNew").css("display", "block");
                $("#stDate").val(date.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            },
        });
        alert(source);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', source, true);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');           
    }
});
```

Then my code C# :

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string[] GetEvents(int userId)
    {
        string sql;
        Recordset rst = new Recordset();


        string eventName = null;
        string stDate = null;
        string edDate = null;
        int j = 0;

        if (AppCode.Utils.DB_Connect())
        {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE Users_idUsers = 1";
            rst.Open(sql, AppCode.Utils.ocn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, -1);

            if(!rst.EOF)
            {  
                while (!rst.EOF)
                {
                    eventName += rst.Fields["EventName"].Value.ToString() + '#' + rst.Fields["StartDate"].Value.ToString() + '#' + rst.Fields["EndDate"].Value.ToString()+'&';                       
                    rst.MoveNext();
                    j++;
                }

            }
            if (rst.State > 0)
                rst.Close();

        }
        AppCode.Utils.DB_Disconnect();

        eventName = eventName.Substring(0, eventName.Length - 1);
        string[] events = eventName.Split('&');

        string final = "";

        foreach (var item in events)
        {
            string[] elements = item.Split('#');
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(elements[1]);
            stDate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            DateTime ft = new DateTime();
            ft = Convert.ToDateTime(elements[2]);

            edDate = ft.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");               

            final += "{  title: '" + elements[0] + "',start: '" + stDate + "',end: '" + edDate + "'}#";
        }

        final = final.Substring(0, final.Length - 1);
        string[] eventsArray = final.Split('#');
        return eventsArray;
    }
```

Firebug says that there is an error :

```
TypeError: eventProps.start is undefined


eventProps.allDay = !(eventProps.start.hasTime() || (eventProps.end && eventProp...
```

My records, for instance d[0] look like that :

```
"{  title: 'aaa',start: '2016-12-11',end: '2016-12-11'}"
```

Have you an issue how to fix this error ? May i'm in a wrong way ? Or there is an other issue to display the events ? 
I search a lot from the internet and the doc of FullCalendar but i don't find the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your data is valid the only thing you need to do to make it work is to delete

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', source, true);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

and instead keep only this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
```

Having said that, I would recommend you to use the ajax call within the fullCalendar initialization using [eventSources](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/).

> "You can put any number of event arrays, functions, JSON feed URLs, or full-out Event Source Objects into the eventSources array."

You'll probably want to use the function and filter dates by the current view (and not load the entire history of the events) so it will render it automatically according to the view (Remember that you need to adjust your server function to support it).